# How to bind to a collection of UDT in Cassandra C++ driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I have a table with a column of type `LIST<FROZEN<custom_type>` where custom_type is a UDT, user defined type (`CREATE TYPE custom_type...`).

In the Datastax C++ driver, how do I bind values to this column?

I tried to:

```
CassDataType* udt = cass_keyspace_meta_user_type_by_name("keyspace_name", "custom_type");
CassCollection* coll = cass_collection_new_from_data_type("custom_type", 5);
for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ++ii)
{
    CassUserType* usr = cass_user_type_new_from_data_type(udt);
    cass_user_type_set_string_by_name(usr, "udt_name_1", data[ii].stringvalue);
    cass_user_type_set_int32_by_name(usr, "udt_name_2", data[ii].intvalue);
    cass_collection_append_user_type(coll, usr);
    cass_user_type_free(usr);
}
cass_statement_bind_collection_by_name(stmt, "column_name", coll);
```

This code fails in the second line, where `cass_collection_new_from_data_type()` returns NULL. udt is not NULL.

From the source code of `cass_collection_new_from_data_type()`, this function returns NULL if the parameter is `!is_collection()`, which mine obviously is not. So is this function `cass_collection_new_from_data_type()` supposed to do that? How am I supposed to get a CassCollection* to bind to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify real collection type, not your user-defined type:

```
    CassCollection* phone = cass_collection_new(CASS_COLLECTION_TYPE_LIST, 5);
```

and leave the rest as-is.  See [examples/udt/udt.c](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/examples/udt/udt.c#L110) as example.

Comment: Follow-up question: What is `cass_collection_new_from_data_type()` for? The API documentation http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/api/struct.CassCollection/ is so incomplete!

Comment: [`cass_collection_data_type`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/latest/api/cassandra.h/#function-cass_collection_data_type) will allow you to get a reference to the data type for a given collection. From there the [`cass_collection_new_from_data_type`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/latest/api/struct.CassCollection/#function-cass_collection_new_from_data_type) can be used to create a new instance of the collection. There does appear to be some documentation issues between the class/structs and the header file. Hope that clears things up a bit.